# How do I create a bootable Windows ISO from VMDK disk files?

Tags: windows-10, boot, vmware, iso-image

I use VMware Workstation to create virtual development machines for my development needs running Visual Studio 2017 RC and SQL Server 2016.

Now I need that same environment on a physical machine. This is what I envision

1. Create a bootable Windows 10 usb having the same software as my virtual machine so I can just install it on that physical machine and viola I have Win 10 + VS 2017 + SQL Server 2016

I researched and found post on creating iso from vmdk files. I created an iso using poweriso from the vmdk files of my dev machine however it does not work.

I found [this](http://vmwstudio.blogspot.in/2010/06/create-bootable-iso-installer-from-your.html) but this is for linux.

What is the best way to achieve my vision?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Why not simply sysprep, then clone the hard disk?

Comment: @gronostaj Will sysprep cover the Visual Studio + SQL Server installation as well?

Comment: It's designed for this specific task. You prepare the system image on one machine, then use sysprep to turn it into a generic image, then clone it to a number of systems. It should work, you can snapshot the VM and give it a try.